# Convert Date to UTC with timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, luxon

I'm migrating some data in my DB and have date as a string `"date" : "2020-10-23",`. I want to convert that date into a datetime object to store it in another field. I'm using [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html)

```js
let DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

// Function
function timeZoneToUTC(timezone, year, month, day, hours) {
  const dateObj = `${year}-${month}-${day} ${hours}:00`;
  let date = DateTime.fromFormat(dateObj, 'yyyy-M-d H:mm', {
    zone: timezone
  });
  return date.toUTC().toString();
}

// Example
let record = {preparationTime: "18",
              date : "2020-10-23"};
let dateISO = DateTime.fromISO(record.date, {zone: 'Europe/Amsterdam'});
dateISO = dateISO.minus({days: 1});
let year = dateISO.year;
let month = dateISO.month;
let day = dateISO.day;

record.newOrderTime = timeZoneToUTC('Europe/Amsterdam', year, month, day, 22);

console.log(record.newOrderTime);
```

```html
<script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.25.0/build/global/luxon.min.js" > </script>
```

The code above returns a wrong time, for example: `2020-10-23` will be `2020-10-22T20:00:00.000Z` the day is correct however the time is not, it should be 21 instead of 20

Comment: 2020-10-23T00:00:00 in Amsterdam was 2020-10-22T22:00:00Z, i.e. two hours earlier as the offset in Amsterdam on that date was +2 hours (daylight saving time in Amsterdam, CEDT). At 03:00 on Sunday 25 October the offset changed to +1 (standard time in Amsterdam, CEST).

Answer (score 0):

This maybe due to Daylight savings times. (https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/zones.html#dst-weirdness)

To check whether current time is based on DST or not
[https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-get-isInDST](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#instance-get-isInDST)